# MetroPanel scroll position not resetting when MetroTiles are removed

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

**UPDATE:**
I didn't mention that I was also using a `MetroTabControl` because I didn't think it was relevant.  However, I did some more testing and below are my results.  I will also post this as an answer to my own question.

1. The `MetroPanel` that's causing the problem is on a different tab than the buttons that update it

I put a different `MetroPanel` on the same tab as the offending buttons and viola, this panel worked perfectly fine.  I proceeded to delete the original `MetroPanel` and recreate it on the separate tab page.  This appears to have fixed the problem.  I have no idea how, but there it is.

**Original Text:**
This is the situation:

1. `MetroModernUI` package by Dennis Magno, v1.4.0 Is installed in the
   solution
2. `MetroPanel` on a `MetroForm`, `AutoScroll` set to true to handle horizontal
   tiles
3. `MetroTiles` are created at run time based off a given configuration
4. When the configuration is changed, all the tiles are unloaded and reloaded

**Note:** I’m not worried about the performance implications of unloading and reloading all of the tiles each time.  I don’t anticipate needing more than 10 at a time.

**The problem:**
When the horizontal scrollbar is positioned all the way to the right of the panel, and a `MetroTile` is removed and doesn’t reset. This causes the scroll position to be outside of the actual scrollable area, as best I can tell. This causes flickering and my `MetroTiles` don’t actually show up. I’ve tried everything I can think of with the related scroll properties but I’m at a loss.  You can see in the following snippets that I am using `AutoScrollPosition` and `HorizontalScroll.Value` to try and reset it, but it just doesn’t reset.

**Example:**
Here's a GIF of what’s happening:
https://gyazo.com/362b83abae795f728675a3c11fcf6a29

**Code:**

```
public void LoadTiles(MetroPanel panel)
{
    foreach (Feed feed in Feeds.GetFeedsFromConfig())
    {
        var tile = CreateTile(feed);
        AddTile(panel, tile);
    }

}
public void UnloadTiles(MetroPanel panel)
{

    var tiles = panel.Controls.OfType<MetroTile>().ToArray();
    for(var i = tiles.Count()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        panel.Controls.Remove(tiles[i]);
        tiles[i].Dispose();
    }
    panel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);
    panel.HorizontalScroll.Value = 0;
}
public void AddTile(MetroPanel panel, MetroTile tile)
{
    var numTiles = panel.Controls.OfType<MetroTile>().Count();
    tile.Location = new Point(numTiles * 155, 0);
    panel.Controls.Add(tile);
}
public MetroTile CreateTile(Feed feed)
{
    MetroTile tile = new MetroTile();
    tile.Text = feed.Name;
    tile.Style = MetroColorStyle.Purple;
    tile.TileTextFontSize = MetroTileTextSize.Tall;
    tile.UseStyleColors = true;
    tile.Theme = MetroThemeStyle.Dark;
    tile.Tag = feed;
    tile.Click += new EventHandler(LoadFeedInBrowser);
    tile.Size = new Size(150, 100);
    return tile;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't mention that I was also using a `MetroTabControl` because I didn't think it was relevant.  However, I did some more testing and below are my results.  I will also post this as an answer to my own question.

1. The `MetroPanel` that's causing the problem is on a different tab than the buttons that update it

I put a different `MetroPanel` on the same tab as the offending buttons and viola, this panel worked perfectly fine.  I proceeded to delete the original `MetroPanel` and recreate it on the separate tab page.  This appears to have fixed the problem.  I have no idea how, but there it is.  My only guess is that I somehow screwed up the properties of the original `MetroPanel`